# Ckeditor plugin functionality not working after using setData("hai");

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm using the ck-editor(4.4.6). In Ck-editor's textarea I want to update my text, for that I use **setData("hai");** that text updating correctly but some plugin functionality not working after use this setData(); (eg. restrict multiple enter if I reload the page it's working correctly).

`editorInstance.setData("test text");`

> Anyway first time and after reload the page it working fine.

`ruby on rails with jquery things are I'm using.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: It might be because some versions use classic editor which uses an iframe and the iframe does not work if it's detached from DOM.

You can have a look here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ckeditor-tickets/inJ4iosX-eU

Comment: @SG1Asgard - thanks for you reply my actual problem content is loading while editing that content plugin functionality not working. If i reload the same thing working. It's happen not only chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer instead of set data I just add my content to CKEditor text area as link this its working fine:

```
$('#cke_editor1 iframe').contents().find('body').html("Your text");
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about ck-editor(4.4.6) but i can give you a way to solve it. You have to use based on your parent class. First time it works because it was same but after that it did't find the class/your specific term/attribute. So you have to use by calling parent class/id and under your activity.

Comment: I'm using this editor instance not only single place. If i call with parent class or id, Its a way to duplicate the code. Am i correct?. One more thing this shown already attached

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the update element function after setting the data, this will actually set the value in the field.
And, also you will need to specify the id of the textarea as given below.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.id_of_textarea.setData('hai');
CKEDITOR.instances.id_of_textarea.updateElement();
```

Comment: `editorInstance.updateElement()` is used for update **ckeditor content  to normal textarea**. the editor's functionality problem is still happen.